# beginner in python, if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

```
score = raw_input("Enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0:")

float(score)

#if score < 0.0:
    #print "Invalid input."
    #exit

#elif score > 1.0:
    #print "Invalid input."
    #exit

if score >= .9:
    print "A"

elif score >= .8:
    print "B"

elif score >= .7:
    print "C"

elif score >= .6:
    print "D"

elif score < .6:
    print "F"

else:
    print "Invalid input."
```

I'm having trouble with the above python code; something seems wrong with my initial if statement but I can't seem to figure out what. No matter what input I test it with, it always returns A as the output. Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong would be great, sorry for such a simple question but I just started learning python, I've been staring at this code for over an hour and I can't figure out for the life of me why it's not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of the `float()` call *back* to `score`:

```
score = float(score)
```

`score` starts out as a string, an immutable object, and it'll not be converted in-place. `float()` returns a *new* float object, and you are ignoring that return value.

Rather than use 5 `if` statements, you can use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to map a value to a letter:

```
import bisect

score = float(raw_input("Enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0:"))

scores = [0, .6, .7, .8, .9]
grades = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']

print grades[bisect.bisect(scores, score) - 1]
```

For any given score, `bisect.bisect()` will return the insertion point into the `scores` list *after* the nearest lower or equal value; so for `.9` it'll return `5`, to insert the value at the end, but for anything from `0` up to (but not including) `0.6` it'll return `1`.

All you then have to do is subtract 1 and use the same index into the `grades` list instead to get the corresponding grade.

Demo:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> scores = [0, .6, .7, .8, .9]
>>> grades = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
>>> bisect.bisect(scores, .75)
3
>>> grades[bisect.bisect(scores, .75) - 1]
'C'
>>> grades[bisect.bisect(scores, .25) - 1]
'F'
>>> grades[bisect.bisect(scores, .9) - 1]
'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't actually change the variable `score` to a `float`

```
float(score)
```

You have to assign it back to `score`

```
score = float(score)
```

Or just do so as you input the variable

```
score = float(raw_input("Enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

just save that value in score again.

```
 score = float(score)
```